# Android 4.0 shows wrong time zone for outlook calendar item sent through CDO

Tags: android, calendar, exchange-server

Calendar items sent through Microsoft CDO are formatted differently from calendar items sent directly through Exchange. The CDO formatting results in the appointment being at the wrong time when opened in Android 4.0.

The examples below are extracted from .ics files received on a Droiz Razr running ICS.

Both appointments were sent from Outlook 2011 clients. I tried both the native Android mail client and the K-9 mail client. It appears the mail client (generically) does not process the file and simply passes it to the OS. It seems the object is opened by the calendar app. (it is not clear to me why some Outlook clients are connected through CDO and why some are connected directly through Exchange, as all the desktop are on the same LAN.)

Example1, CDO:

PRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange
...

DTSTART;TZID="(GMT-08.00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)":20120921T110000
...

Example 2, EXchange 2007:

PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2007
...

DTSTART;TZID=Pacific Standard Time:20120921T110000
...

IN both cases, I am located in CST while the server is in PST.
However, example 1 shows up 2 hours early in the calendar (seems to ignore or not understand the TZID setting) while example 2 shows up correctly.

It seems to be related to the different formatting of the time zone. It seems Android does not recognize the DTSTART formatting from the CDO and assumes it is local time.

Is there a patch or a way to patch Android so that the time zone is interpreted correctly?

Thanks in advance

dj